# How to add data files to a wheel distribution?

Tags: python, packaging, python-packaging, python-wheel

So i'm doing a python package for my dissertation with the following structure:

```
 ├── dist
    │   └── segtest-0.0.8.tar.gz
    ├── README.md
    ├── result
    ├── setup.py
    ├── src
    │   ├── segmentation
    │   │   ├── data
    │   │   │   ├── atlas_flargas
    │   │   │   │   ├── atlas_info.txt
    │   │   │   │   └── bundles
    │   │   │   │       ├── atlas_AR_ANT_LEFT_MNI.bundles
    │   │   │   │       ├── atlas_AR_ANT_LEFT_MNI.bundlesdata
    │   │   │   │       ├── atlas_AR_ANT_RIGHT_MNI.bundles
    │   │   │   │       ├── atlas_AR_ANT_RIGHT_MNI.bundlesdata
    │   │   │   │       └── ... (there is about 10k of these)
    │   │   │   ├── atlas_fshort
    │   │   │   │   ├── atlasInfo_left.txt
    │   │   │   │   ├── atlasInfo_right.txt
    │   │   │   │   ├── Left_Bundles
    │   │   │   │   │   ├── atlas_lh_CMF_CMF_0i_MNI.bundles
    │   │   │   │   │   ├── atlas_lh_CMF_CMF_0i_MNI.bundlesdata
    │   │   │   │   │   ├── ... (lots of these files)
    │   │   │   │   └── Right_Bundles
    │   │   │   │       ├── atlas_rh_CMF_CMF_0i_MNI.bundles
    │   │   │   │       ├── atlas_rh_CMF_CMF_0i_MNI.bundlesdata
    │   │   │   │       ├── ... (lots of these files)
    │   │   │   └── subjects
    │   │   │       ├── 118225
    │   │   │       │   ├── 118225.bundles
    │   │   │       │   ├── 118225.bundlesdata
    │   │   │       │   └── 118225_nqac.nii
    │   │   │       ├── 157336
    │   │   │       │   ├── 157336.bundles
    │   │   │       │   ├── 157336.bundlesdata
    │   │   │       │   └── 157336_nqac.nii
    │   │   │       └── 157437
    │   │   │           ├── 157437.bundles
    │   │   │           ├── 157437.bundlesdata
    │   │   │           └── 157437_nqac.nii
    │   │   ├── fibras_segmentation.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── main
    │   │   └── main.cpp
    │   └── segtest.egg-info
    │       ├── dependency_links.txt
    │       ├── PKG-INFO
    │       ├── SOURCES.txt
    │       └── top_level.txt
    └── tests
        ├── MANIFEST.in
        └── pyproject.toml
```

I'm trying to include the entire `data` directory + `main.cpp` and hopefully, keeping it's structure, to a wheel distribution since, to my understanding, it is a faster and more user friendly distribution.

I managed to include both the `data` directory and the `main.cpp` file with the source dist by using a `MANIFEST.in` + `include_package_data = True` in my setup.py, but it seems like `MANIFEST.in` is ignored when building a wheel dist. Thus, why i've hid it under the `tests` directory, for the sake of testing other methods for the wheel dist.

I also tried using different `setuptools.setup` options, like:

```
  package_dir = {"": "src"},
  packages = setuptools.find_packages(where="src"),
  include_package_data = True,
  data_files = [('data/atlas_flargas/bundles',['src/segmentation/data/atlas_flargas/bundles/*'])]
```

using `package_data` and have looked through other similar questions, however, all to no avail, since i haven't managed to include any data file whatsoever. I'm very unsure as to how to do this, since i'm very new to the python packaging world. Is it possible to add a whole set of data files (10k+ files) to a wheel distribution? Should i just go for the source distribution for these requirements?